# Difference between a participant and organization in hyperlrdger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to create participants (bank employe) in hyperledger composer . So how do i achieve this that all the bank employees come under a single organization of its bank

Answer (score 0):

Basically the organization concepts it has more importance in the Hyperledger Fabric.

For example we can take the example of banks, if you have two organizations these could be:

1. Bank 1
2. Bank 2

Regarding the participants (bank emplyee) those are more familiarized with the Composer specifically the Business Network Definition

If you want the participants can have an identity that allow them to interact with the Business Network as an Admin.

If you want more information, or an example I wrote two post that helps you to setup and publish an hyperledger fabric with a published Business Network

[Setup an Hyperledger Fabric in Multiple Hosts](https://medium.com/1950labs/setup-hyperledger-fabric-in-multiple-physical-machines-d8f3710ed9b4)

[Publish a Business Network in multi jose Hyperledger Fabric](https://medium.com/1950labs/publish-a-business-network-in-multi-host-hyperledger-fabric-a5ad2015a487)